# Can I pass a variable in for a related model in getattr()?

Tags: python, django

So this works:

```
field_name = 'msrp'

price = getattr(mymodel.related_model, field_name)
```

But I'd like to pass in a variable for the 'related_model', something like:

```
field_name = 'msrp'
x = related_model_name

price = getattr(mymodel.x, field_name)
```

Clearly that does not work, but it shows what I'd like to accomplish.  Is there a way to pass in a variable as the placeholder for the related model name in some manner?

Comment: Why not `getattr(mymodel, x).msrp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `price = getattr(mymodel.related_model, 'msrp')` makes not much sense, since this is imply equivalent to `price = mymodel.related_model.msrp`. If the name of the `related_model` is stored in a variable, you can however use [**`getattr(…)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to obtain the related model object:

```
x = related_model_name

price = getattr(mymodel, x).msrp
```

or if both are strings, you can use `getattr` twice:

```
x = related_model_name
msrp = field_name

price = getattr(getattr(mymodel, x), msrp)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I should be more precise.  In my example above, I'm passing in 'msrp' as a string variable already, so if I follow your example I now have the same problem with 'msrp'.  I'll edit my example to reflect that.

Comment: @sc_props: then you can use `getattr` twice. See edit.

Comment: I did not think to nest getattr() like that!  So reversing your example variable to field_name = 'msrp', it works just fine. Excellent solution, thank you.